# use unique string match as header when importing Excel dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have some messy Excel spreadsheets and want to import a small number of cells into a dataframe. The number of rows and columns containing info I'm uninterested in (**"."**) and cells with whitespace (**~**) varies from spreadsheet to spreadsheet.

Here's an example of an spreadsheet (input):

```
~   ~   ~   ~   
.   .   .   .   .
~   .   .   .   
.   .   .   .   .
~   ~   ~       
~   Name    ID  Description Notes
12  a   AA  aA  None
3   b   BB  bB  sentence one
44  c   CC  cC  None
9   d   DD  dD  Int
```

Is my logic correct that I need to import the full spreadsheet into a dataframe first, then parse that dataframe for the unique string (**Name**) as the header line into a second dataframe to use?

This is how I'm importing but am stuck on the parsing to second dataframe:

```
import pandas
file = 'example.xlsx'
xl = pandas.ExcelFile(file, dtype=str) #some cells have values and want just as strings
df = xl.parse("Sheet1")
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for cell in row:
        if 'Name' in str(cell):
            header_start_row = index
            break
```

Desired pandas dataframe (output):

```
Name    ID  Description Notes
a   AA  aA  None
b   BB  bB  sentence one
c   CC  cC  None
d   DD  dD  Int
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`pandas.read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) function to import your excel sheet. It has an optional input argument `skiprows` that allows you to specify the rows at the top that should be ignored.

```
import pandas as pd

file = 'example.xlsx'
skiprows_amount = 5
df = pd.read_excel(file, skiprows=range(skiprows_amount), dtype=str)
```

Note: this solution has the limitation that you have to know the amount of to-be-skipped rows in advance.

Comment: pd.read_excel(file, skiprows=range(header_start_row)) might work to collapse the rows

Comment: @lcb Yes, that's a nice improvement.

Comment: it should start at the sixth row but `header_start_row` gives 3, not 6